# Не могу создать триггер в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хочу создать триггер который будет автоматически подвязывать поле `Id`, из таблицы 
`users`, с `UserID` из таблицы `profiles`

Вот код на T-SQL :

```
    create table users (
   Id int not null primary key identity,
   Username varchar(30) not null unique,
   Email varchar(30) not null unique,
);
create table profiles (
    Id int primary key identity,
    UserId int not null references users(Id) ,
    Name varchar(30) not null,
);
go
create trigger new_profile on users after insert as
 for each row 
 begin
  insert into profiles(UserId) values (new.Id);
  end
```

Главная ошибка возле `for each row` , где при создании триггера получаю такую ошибку :

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.`

Не могли бы вы помочь с решением проблемы , спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо пытаться использовать Oracle диалект в SQL Server.

Попробуйте так:

```
create trigger new_profile
on users
after insert
as
  insert into profiles(UserId) select Id from inserted;
GO
```

Comment: как раз уже в писал в ответе о оракле и хотел навести пример - сделал подобный код ,действительно помогло,спасибо!

Comment: @MaxNavrotsky, пожалуйста :)